# doParallel computing using caret error message

Tags: r, multiprocessing, r-caret, doparallel

I have been trying to implement multi-core processing with library(doParallel) but somehow one error kept showing up. I doubt it is an error generated from doParallel package. Below is my code (I skip the data processing part to make the code simple):

```
library(caret)
library(doParallel)
cores=detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-2)
registerDoParallel(cl)


ctrl<-trainControl(method='cv',number=5, classProbs = T, 
               summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, allowParallel = T)

#############
#XGBoost Tree
#############
xgb_grid<-expand.grid(
  nrounds = 500,
  max_depth = 5,
  eta = c(0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12),
  gamma = 0.3,
  colsample_bytree = 0.25,
  min_child_weight = 2,
  subsample = 0.5
)

xgb <- caret::train(y ~ .,                 
             data = train,        
             method = "xgbTree",    
             trControl = ctrl,      
             tuneGrid = xgb_grid,   
             metric = "ROC",        
             verbose = TRUE)
stopCluster(c1)
```

And I got below error:

```
Error in e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) : 
  worker initialization failed: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ 
in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = 
vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘generics’
```

I'm not sure what's the reason. It seems like doParallel has issue running caret? I do know that under trainControl the allowParallel function can allow the models to use multicore if needed, but not for all the models. That's why I want to force caret to use multicore to train the model.

Comment: Did you install package generics?

Comment: Yes, I did. But the same error showed up.

Comment: I'm using remote server on linux for this. I wonder could it be the reason that the doParallel library cannot locate the generics package? If so, how can I specify the path for the code to run?

Comment: Which remote server? Please provide a minimal reproducible example including data eg using dput function.

Comment: It remembers me the option '.packages' of foreach. Each cores seems to be a R environment and so doesn't have loaded all packages in main environment. It might be something similar.